# How to use GET in ReactJS web chat app with Rest API back-end?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a chat app using ReactJS for a class project web app. For the back-end I am using Rest API. So ideally when I post something on the chat, I would use POST and when I receive a message from the other end, I would use GET. In terms of POST, I figure I can associate that with an event, such as pushing the submit button for the chat app. However, I am racking my mind for how I would call GET for receiving a message. Would it be as simple as using a React life cycle function, such as ComponentDidMount to call GET for receiving a message? Or would I need to use a timer with one of those functions? Or is there a radically different method altogether? From what I see of the life cycle functions, they only update based on changes in state and props.

Comment: This really isn't answerable in this site's format, because there are too many possible options.  Either option you presented *could* work;  in practice, however, something like a web socket framework would be more appropriate.

Comment: Use Socket.io on both server & client, if you wrote the server. Otherwise, you may have to poll the server, i.e. use timeout for GET

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot of questions you have there. I will provide one possible solution.

1. Choose or implement chat UI, I recommend using https://github.com/PeterKottas/react-bell-chat as it's very easy to setup.
2. Implement backend, I recommend dot net core as it's fairly easy to wire this up in that framework.
3. Forget GET-ing messages on a timer. Imagine you have 1000 users getting every 5 seconds. That's a home-brew DDOS attack. Instead use bidirectional communication.
4. SignalR is the library that can help you implement that, you google the official repo, there's plenty of examples.
5. Connect to signalR on front end using the javascript (or typescript) client they provide.
6. And you're pretty much done.

Here they use angular but you should get the gist of it https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-signalr-chat-angular/